# Как сделать поиск через url?

Tags: url, search

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как можно сделать поиск через url?  
Например:

```
http://site.ru  
http://site.ru/contact.html  
http://site.ru/about.html  
http://site.ru/download.html и т. д.
```

И еще:

```
url: http://mail.ru 
title: Mail.Ru: почта, поиск в интернете, новости, игры 
body: Почта Mail.Ru — крупнейшая бесплатная почта, быстрый и удобный интерфейс, неограниченный объем ящика, надежная защита от спама и вирусов, мобильная версия и приложения для смартфонов. Доступ по IMAP, SMS-уведомления, интерфейс на разных языках и темы оформления Почты. Также на Mail.Ru: новости, поиск в интернете, авто, спорт, игры, знакомства, погода, работа.
```

И можно найти автоматический скрипт?
Где можно найти php код? Помогите или, если есть, дайте, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

Comment: @Vahan Av, мне нужно без гуугл и яндекс

Comment: @romeo, а не нужно данное создание причислять к данному сообществу. Да и вообще причем тут php???

Comment: @Gedweb Всё просто. По профилю ТС можно понять, куда он метит.

Каждый раз, когда я сталкиваюсь с подобной ситуацией в голове всплывает данная крылатая фраза. Будь-то в подкастах, на тв короткая беседа про php заканчивалась именно этими словами. А ведь он прав. Слишком низкое качество. Иногда мне кажется, что ["дворники" захватили планету](http://goo.gl/WFHxVH).

Comment: @Gedweb Кончено, есть и светлые пятна: [Никита Попов](http://goo.gl/kFKEE7), [Дмитрий Стогов](http://goo.gl/wDQzm7), [Андрей Нигматуллин](http://goo.gl/1ws91A),[Василий Зорин](http://goo.gl/j3U4HX), [Александр Макаров](http://goo.gl/3tjSZs),...

И да, я часть этого сообщества.

Comment: Люди ну зачем сразу тролить то. Ну не смог человек Выразить мысль.
Можно ему помочь и подсказать как правильно выражаться, а не пинать.

Ведь все когда-то начинали и хотя бы раз задавали не те вопросы.

Comment: @romeo "моляры" + "стыдно за..." в одном сообщении = бомба

Comment: @Vahan Av Я ТС дал наводящий вопрос

> Может Вы про [роутинг по url-у](https://laravel.ru/docs/v4/routing)?

То ли не заметил, то ли действительно про fullsearch речь шла.

Да, и здесь я был лишь немного разочарован, не более. А вот [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/400987/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0) я был рассержен.

Comment: @Etki [Не копируй](https://vk.com/wall-30666517_991096?reply=991266) на ночь глядя ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну в этом случае из коробки варианты вряд ли найдете.

Придется серьезно поработать с поисковыми системами (search engine). 
Вот пара хороших, на мой взгляд:

http://sphinxsearch.com

Sphinx подойдёт вам, если необходимо индексировать большие объёмы данных в базе MySQL и вам важна скорость индексации и поиска, однако не требуются специфические возможности поиска вроде “fuzzy search” и вы согласны выделить на это отдельный сервер или даже кластер.

http://lucene.apache.org

Если необходимо встроить поисковый модуль в ваше приложение, то лучше всего поиска готовые порты для вашего языка к библиотеке Lucene — для всех распространённых языков они есть, однако могут реализовывать далеко не все возможности оригинала. Для РНР это, по всей видимости, единственный приемлемый вариант полной реализации поиска без дополнительных модулей и расширений.  Однако учтите достаточную медленную индексации и необходимость частой оптимизации индекса (и требовательность к CPU и скорости диска).

Вот нашел сравнение движков [тут](http://lib.custis.ru/Сравнение_движков_полнотекстового_поиска#.D0.A1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0).

Comment: Ещё можно добавить [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

Comment: Спасибо и один вопрос есть php мощный поисковик (движок)?

Comment: @KYRAN "есть php мощный поисковик" это врядли, медленый php для этого.
Но примеры реализации для php есть почти для всех движков.

Да и спасибо @romeo за напоминание elasticsearch про него я как-то забыл.

Comment: @Vahan Av Я за отечественного производителя - за [Андрюшу Аксёнова](http://habrahabr.ru/users/shodan/). Тем более, его проект написан на плюсах.

Comment: @romeo Те всетаки сфикс )).
Во а что человеку свой ORM не предлагаеш.

@KYRAN https://github.com/romeOz/rock-sphinx. Может понравится.

Comment: @Vahan Av, Sphinx Search мне очень понравилось! Но я новичок, даже не знаю, как использовать движок! Как закачать файлы на хостинг? Я сделал, но ничего не получилось. Помогите, пожалуйста, как установить?

Comment: @KYRAN Я же писал "и вы согласны выделить на это отдельный сервер или даже кластер". Если у вас нет возможности приобрести и настроить отдельный сервер, то, скорее всего, ваш сайт даже и не нуждается в полнотекстовом поисковом движке. Лучше обойтись простым SQL-ом. Или воспользоваться гуглом. А если вам мешает реклама, то у них, насколько я помню, можно за 100 зеленых в год от нее можно избавиться.

Comment: @Vahan Av, Спасибо!

Comment: @Vahan Av Я бы "свой ORM" взял в кавычки. Моя заслуга в нём > 10%. Внедрил [свой кэш](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-cache), [data provider](http://goo.gl/Dar4R3) (вывод с пагинацией), [select builder](http://goo.gl/q3Xqd9), а главное, сделал полностью независимым (standalone) модулем (в yii, как известно, отсутствует модульность). Аналогичным образом я поступил с [Rock DB](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-db) и [Rock MongoDB](http://goo.gl/T39DTF). Зачем писать свои "велосипеды", если есть готовые решения, выполненные в едином интерфейсе.

> ...не предлагаешь

Кхм, как бы помягче - не стоит :)